# How to increase multi dimension of array in tensorflow?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, tensorflow, concatenation

I have a txt file which has 8 columns and I am selecting 1 column for my feature extraction which gives me 13 features values, the shape of output array will be [1x13].
Similarly I have 5 txt files in a folder I want to run a loop so that the returned variable will have 5x13 data.

```
def loadinfofromfile(directory,sd,channel):
    # subdir selection and read file names in it for particular crack type.
    subdir, filenames = loadfilenamesindirectory(directory,sd)
    for i in range(5):
        # join the directory sub directory and the filename
        loadfile = os.path.join(directory,subdir,filenames[i])
        # load the values of that paticular file into tensor
        fileinfo = tf.constant(np.loadtxt(loadfile),tf.float32)
        # select the particular column data ( choosen from crack type, channel no)
        fileinfo_trans = tf.transpose(fileinfo)
        fileinfo_back = tf.gather(fileinfo_trans,channel)
        # extracting features from selected column data gives [1x13]
        pool = features.pooldata(fileinfo_back)
        poolfinal = tf.concat_v2([tf.expand_dims(pool,0)],axis=0)
    return poolfinal
```

In the above function I am able to get [1x13] to the variable 'pool' and I am expecting the size of the variable poolfinal as [5x13] but i get it as [1x13].
how to concat in vertical direction ?
What is the mistake i did in the loop ?

Answer (score 0):

each loop creates pool and poolfinal from sctratch. That's why you see only one data in poolfinal.
instead please try following:

```
pools = []
for ...:
  pools.append(...)
poolfinal = tf.concat_v2(pools, axis=0)
```

Comment: when I am using pool.append I need not copy again that in to poolfinal, I want to do it using tensorflow function concat_v2